# Windows azure emulator 127.0.0.1:81 not accessible in internet explorer

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io

I am using some example code, http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/app-using-socketio/, to create a basic socket.io app with the WorkerRole.  Upon starting the emulator, I go to access: 127.0.0.1:81, but IE will not load the page saying it's not accessible.

Here is the output of powershell

```
PS Y:\Project\WorkerRole1> Start-AzureEmulator -launch
Creating local package...
Starting Emulator...
Role is running at tcp://127.0.0.1:81
Role is running at tcp://127.0.0.1:8
Started
```

Edit: Another note, I am using the Parallels VM with Windows 8 on OSX 10.8.2

Comment: and if you just `TELNET 127.0.0.1 81` what is the result?

Comment: The example shows it opening in http:// in a browser.  If i do telnet from the command line, it says its not a recognized command

Comment: TELNET can be installed from `Programs & Features` -> `Add/Remove Windows Components` -> there select `Telnet client` and install. An invaluable tool for a developer.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the value of `process.env.port` to see if it's 80 or 81. This might because you are listening on 80 but the local emulator use 81.